# javascript closure or not (while using angularjs directive and d3js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

Inspired by this example [angular directive with 2-way binding](http://creative-punch.net/2016/02/exchange-data-directive-controller-angularjs/), I made a simple directive, once clicked will change the value on the parent scope [codepen live](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GowNvP?editors=1010).

```
.directive("haha", function() {
return {
  scope: {
    v: '='
  },
  template: `<div ng-click="myfun()">click me now</div>`,
  link: function(scope, element) {
    scope.myfun = function() {
      scope.v  = "clicked";
    }       
  }
}
});
```

Now I add a svg circle drawn with d3 inside "link", and try to add a similar event handler with `d3.on`

```
d3.select(element[0]).append("svg").attr({width:300,height:300})
      .append("circle").attr({cx:100,cy:100,r:20})
      .on("click",function(){scope.v="clicked inside d3"; alert(scope.v)});
```

When I click the circle, `{{value}}` on html page doesn't change. [codepen live](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GowNQz?editors=1010)

Isn't it correct, as javascript closure rule, inside `on("click", function() ...`, `scope.v` should still be the same as `scope` from `link: function(scope...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [scope.$apply](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) since you are updating your scope "outside" the "angular world" and you want angular to run a digest cycle.

```
d3.select(element[0]).append("svg").attr({width:300,height:300})
      .append("circle").attr({cx:100,cy:100,r:20})
      .on("click",function(){scope.$apply(function(){scope.v="clicked inside d3";})});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEQBPV?editors=1010).